# EXC_BAD_ACCESS: what is the meaning of 'code' and 'address'?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm, exc-bad-access, lldb

I know what EXC_BAD_ACCESS means. But it didn't occur to me until now to check what the meaning of the additional parameters is that comes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

For example:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2408b83f)
```

**What does `code=2` indicate, and what does the address point to?**

Code: I've only seen codes 1 and 2 being used. Are there any others and what is their meaning?

Address: I tried 'po' with the address in the LLVM command prompt but did not receive a useful response. I suppose that's the address of the accessed object (which is invalid). Is there any LLDB command other than 'po' using the given address that will or may help narrow down the issue?

Comment: I don't know what code 1 vs code 2, as I rarely have to look beyond the address, and if it's `0x0` it means I used `nil` where `nil` was not permitted (either explicitly used `nil`, or had some `weak` value `nil`-ed when it was released) and if it's not `0x0` (as in this case), then it generally means that I have an invalid pointer (e.g. a dangling pointer to some deallocated object, best diagnosed by turning on zombies).

Comment: Exactly what I do. Though I started wondering whether the experts know some magic tricks that I don't. ;) At least the code part is intruiging but it may be as simple as "nil pointer = 1, non-nil = 2".

Comment: Thanks! I voted to close my own question. :)